# image gallery with tumbnails in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a image thumbnails with `JavaScript` .but is not moving when i click on image .also i want to list same right side how to do .please help me.[this is my page i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJWcX.png)

this is my code

```
<div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event)">
   <image class="imgstyle"   src="images/r1.jpg" />
   <image class="imgstyle" src="images/r2.jpg" />
   <image class="imgstyle" src="images/r3.jpg" />
   <image class="imgstyle" src="images/r4.jpg" />
   <image class="imgstyle" src="images/nw.jpg" />
</div>  <br><br>
```

```
function changeImage(event)
{
 event = event || window.event;

var targetElement = event.target || event.srcelement;

             if(targEtelement.tagname == "IMG")
             {
document.getelEmentbyid("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
             }

}

</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript identifiers are case sensitive, you have several instances of capitalising the wrong letters.

Comment: can you please update your code using snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @core114 Instead of updating in jsfiddle its better to create snippet.

Comment: Dynamic typing strikes again!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from this:

```
document.getelEmentbyid("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
```

to

```
document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: Thank you soo much

Comment: No worries - Can you mark this as the answer for future users? Thanks

Comment: but there is a one problem, i want to use same as another side and 6 sides like that can tell how to get it plz.

Comment: 6 same slider in one page plz help me sir

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is extremely sloppy, it didn't work because the casing of properties and method names was all wrong.

```js
function changeImage(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcelement;

  if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.imgstyle {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.imgstyle + .imgstyle {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<img height="250" width="550" style="border:4px solid grey" src="https://placehold.it/550x250?text=A" id="mainImage" />
<br />
 
<div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event)">
  <image class="imgstyle" src="https://placehold.it/550x250?text=A" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="https://placehold.it/550x250?text=B" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="https://placehold.it/550x250?text=C" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="https://placehold.it/550x250?text=D" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="https://placehold.it/550x250?text=E" />
</div> 
<br><br>
```